# icon inside small button wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to add icon inside small `Button` but it doesn't enters as desired,

here my xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="eye_button"  BorderBrush="{x:Null}"   Margin="234,0,0,0"  Height="15" Width="15">                                     
        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Eye"   Foreground="Black" />
  </Button>
```

Here how it's looks like:

[image]

The left squre it's the button, in the right it's the icon

Comment: Not enough information,Can you paste the entire XAML if possible?

Comment: Try to add Height and Width to icon also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Button x:Name="eye_button" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"  Margin="234,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Eye" Foreground="Black" Width="15" Height="15" />
</Button>
```

It should look like this at runtime:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```html
 <Button
    Width="15"
    Height="15"
    Padding="0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
    Background="Transparent"
    BorderThickness="0"
    Foreground="Red">

    <materialDesign:PackIcon
        Width="15"
        Height="15"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Foreground="Black"
        Kind="ArrowBack" />
</Button>
```

Make sure you put padding to 0

[image]

Comment: Padding on the icon is the key in most-cases.